# How do I disable the notifications in Dynamics CRM 2011 for specific user accounts?

Tags: notifications, dynamics-crm-2011

We are having users in a group, where for any request created in CRM, it will send  e-mail to all of the users in the group.

Most of the times, one person will be monitoring continuously the requests. The group head would like to disable sending e-mail notifications to that specific user.

Is it possible to give user the option to disable e-mails from CRM 2011 to his/her outlook?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware this is not currently possible.  Maybe advise the users to filters these emails out to a separate folder?

Regards

Comment: Do you see is there any control for an administrator at the e-mail router level?

As per my understanding e-mail router should convert a record to e-mail before sending the e-mail to user inbox. Do Admin is having any control at router level to disable this user to get notified as a workaround?

Comment: We don't use the CRM router but my understanding is that it has a plugin model where one can completely customize the router logic. May not be relevant to your situation. Here's [some info](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/dynamicscrmsupportblog/archive/2012/11/09/email-router-demystified-explanation.aspx)